# where does the annotation for a member variable live

Tags: python, annotations, python-3.6, abstract-syntax-tree, inspect

if i do something like this:

```
def f(x: str):
    pass
```

i can easily see this type hint for `x` if i do:

```
print(f.__annotations__)
```

however, i can't seem to figure out where the annotations live if i do something like this:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.where_is_this_vars_annotation_stored: int = 4
```

does anyone know which `__annotations__` dict contains `where_is_this_vars_annotation_stored`'s type hint?

Comment: [`__annotations__` does not exist under class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members).  Perhaps there's a workaround for it.

Comment: `__annotations__` does exist if you do something like `class C: i: int`

Comment: Interesting, perhaps I wasn't looking deep enough.  It seems classes will create `__annotations__` to the mapping when there's annotated class attributes, but not for instance attributes which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up writing something that uses `inspect`, `ast`, `exec`, and `eval` to solve this for me.

https://gist.github.com/sweettuse/f5fa022a0abadf3fc368105fcccc46c1